# $\frac{d}{dx} \int_{x^3}^{x^4} e^{t^2} dt$

Tags: integration

Wouldn't the fundamental theorem of calculus give:

$\frac{d}{dx} \int_{x^3}^{x^4} e^{t^2} dt=\frac{d}{dx}(F(x^4)-F(x^3)$

Where F the antiderivative of $e^{t^2}$. And

$\frac{d}{dx}(F(x^4)-F(x^3)=e^{x^{4^2}}-e^{x^{3^2}}=e^{x^8}-e^{x^{6}}$?

This isn't the answer according to the manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{d}{dx}F(x^4)$ requires the chain rule and the fundamental theorem of calculus:

$$\frac{d}{dx}F(x^4)=4x^3F'(x^4)=4x^3f(x^4)$$

Likewise $\frac{d}{dx}F(x^3)$ also requires the chain rule and the fundamental theorem of calculus:

$$\frac{d}{dx}F(x^3)=3x^2F'(x^3)=3x^2f(x^3)$$